# Solution at $(z+1)f(x) - zf(-x) = x^4$

Tags: problem-solving

I need your help on $(z+1)f(x) - zf(-x) = x^4$

a) Prove f is even.

b) Find $f(x).$

Can you help me?

Comment: How are $x$ and $z$ related?

Comment: z is a number like (-1, 0, 1, 2)

Comment: x can be any number

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: z E Z, x E R if that may helps

Answer (score 1):

$(z+1) f(x) - zf(-x) = x^4\\
z(f(x) - f(-x)) + f(x) = x^4$

The right hand side is even.  Which means that the left hand side is also even.

$z(f(x) - f(-x)) + f(x) = z(f(-x) - f(x)) + f(-x)$

Collect the $f(x)$ terms on one side and the $f(-x)$ terms on the other

$(2z+1)f(x) = (2z+1)f(-x)\\
f(x) = f(-x)$

$f(x)$ is even

$z(f(x) - f(-x)) + f(x) = x^4\\
f(x) = x^4$

Comment: Why at the begging is (z-1)?

Comment: sorry, transcription error

Answer (score 0):

a) Plug in $-x$ for $x$:
$$ (z+1)f(-x)-zf(x)=x^4$$
and subtract from the original equation
$$ f(x)-f(-x)=0$$

b) Substitute $f(-x)$ for $f(x)$:
$$ f(x)=x^4$$

Comment: Can you show me the subtract a bit better?